# error trying to install npm i mapbox/blend in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mapbox, npm-install

i am trying to install mapbox/blend, but when i run npm i @mapbox/blend finish with error and does not install

node -v --> v16.15.1

error log:

```
PS C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\85k> npm i @mapbox/blend 
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\85k\node_modules\mapnik
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\85k\node_modules\mapnik\lib\binding\mapnik.node --module_name=mapnik --module_path=C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\85\node_modules\mapnik\lib\binding --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.9
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.15.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\85k\node_modules\mapnik\lib\binding\mapnik.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/mapnik/v4.5.9/Release/win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 403 Forbidden on https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/mapnik/v4.5.9/Release/win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for mapnik@4.5.9 and node@16.15.1 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 403 Forbidden on https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/mapnik/v4.5.9/Release/win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.15.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.15.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.1 found at "C:\Python310\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2019 (16.11.32510.428) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Python310\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Adrian\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Adrian\\Desktop\\85k\\node_modules\\mapnik\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Adrian\\Desktop\\85k\\node_modules\\mapnik\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Adrian\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Adrian\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\16.15.1\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Adrian\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\16.15.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\Adrian\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\Adrian\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\16.15.1\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Adrian\\Desktop\\85k\\node_modules\\mapnik',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Adrian\\Desktop\\85\\node_modules\\mapnik\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! "mapnik-config" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
npm ERR! programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'mapnik-config --includes' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:259:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Adrian\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\Adrian\\Desktop\\85\\node_modules\\mapnik\\lib\\binding\\mapnik.node" "--module_name=mapnik" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\Adrian\\Desktop\\85\\node_modules\\mapnik\\lib\\binding" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\85\node_modules\mapnik
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.15.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\85k\node_modules\mapnik\lib\binding\mapnik.node --module_name=mapnik --module_path=C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\85k\node_modules\mapnik\lib\binding --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\85k\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Adrian\\Desktop\\85\\node_modules\\@mapbox\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\85\node_modules\mapnik
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.15.1
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.9
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-10T21_58_47_396Z-debug-0.log
```